# delete all except first 100 ones

Tags: mysql

I want to delete all rows where `date` contains `2018` but keep the first 100 ones.

```
delete from archive where date like '2018%' offset 100;
```

Suntax error near `offset 100`.

Comment: OFFSET only works in combination with LIMIT.

Comment: @CBroe, but I have no limit. How to do that?

Comment: Try to delete records by using in clause. Something like that: `delete from archive where id in (select id from archive where date like '2018%' offset 100);`

Comment: @MaximKreschishin That's just a convoluted way to get the same error.

Comment: Pardon. As it happened to be MySql doesn't allow to select from currently modified table. So the query needs to be rewritten as follows: `delete from archive where id in (select id from (select id from archive where date like '2018%' offset 100) query);`

Comment: @MaximKreschishin That's an even more convoluted way to get the same error.

Comment: @JJJ what's the error error?

Comment: @MaximKreschishin "Syntax error near 'offset 100'", as mentioned in question. OFFSET can't be used without LIMIT, as mentioned in the first comment.

Comment: @JJJ Yes. Pardon, my mistake. Thanks for correction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, the problem in your query is using `OFFSET` without `LIMIT`.

**Solution 1:**

One way to delete the desired entries would be giving a row number to each entry, so that you can fetch the primary key of those whose number is greater than `100`. Then, simply use `IN` to delete all entries whose primary key is in the ones selected.

```
DELETE FROM archive WHERE id IN (
   SELECT id FROM (
      SELECT a.id AS id, @r := @r + 1 AS rownum
      FROM archive AS a, (SELECT @r := 0) AS r
      WHERE date LIKE '2018%'
   ) AS t WHERE rownum > 100
);
```

**Solution 2**

Of course, the exact opposite is possible; that is selecting those rows you don't want to delete, get their primary key and use `LIKE` and `NOT IN` to delete everything else.

```
DELETE FROM archive
WHERE date LIKE '2018%' AND id NOT IN (
   SELECT id
   FROM archive
   WHERE date LIKE '2018%'
   LIMIT 100
);
```

---

**Update:**

To counter the problem you're facing with your MariaDB version, using the second solution, simply use another `SELECT` clause to wrap your subquery in another subquery before using `NOT IN`.

```
DELETE FROM archive
WHERE date LIKE '2018%' AND id NOT IN (
   SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT id
      FROM archive
      WHERE date LIKE '2018%'
      LIMIT 100
   ) AS t
);
```

---

**Note:** Where I use `id` use your primary key, if it's not `id`.

Comment: I tried your second query and getting `Syntax error... near '' at line 6` (limit 100)

Comment: Yes, you're right. I had accidentally put a `;` after `100`. It should be fine now.

Comment: Error - This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Comment: Okay, I have one more dirty trick up my sleeve @bonaca. Check out my update.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a limit before offset. Try this. This should work

```
delete from archive where date like '2018%' limit 1945694608375953174 offset 100;
```

Comment: That is very unlikely. I've just tried it in my db. works fine

Comment: Hmm... I'm working im phpMyAdmin and copied your code and tried many times - always getting `Syntax error... near offset 100`

Comment: then go for Angel politis second query. That looks pretty good